# How to do document sharing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dear All,
i am developing Asp.net web application. in that users want to share there documents via my application.. so please guide me how to do Document sharing in my asp.net web application.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this is to have those documents on the server in some kind of store (either database or file system), and then have a wrapper asp.net page, which users enter to see which documents are shared and it also should provide the download capabilities for the shared documents (without showing their real location on the server storage).

If your wrapper asp.net page provided the direct links to the documents, that would make it impossible to disallow downloading documents which are not shared.